# Hide subgrid header in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid-asp.net, subgrid

I have inplemented a JQGrid alog with a subgrid.

I have a requirement of hiding only the subgrid headers(the outer main grid headers should still be visible).

I tried using the following code  $(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv", "#gbox_" + subgrid_id).hide() on subGridRowExpanded ,  which did not solve the problem.

Any help on this will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the header in the gridComplete function from the main grid:

```
gridComplete: function() {
            var rowIds = $("#grid").getDataIDs();
            $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) {
                var subgridNameBasedOnRowId = "somesubgrid_" + rowId; //the name of my subgrid
                $(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv", "#gbox_" + subgridNameBasedOnRowId).hide();
            });
        }
```